I have a 125v 30amp round fuse blew inside my house and it’s to late to get one from store can I swap one out
Fuse panel inside my house I need to know can I swap one fuse to another because I have no power on one side of the house

How many 30A fuses does your panel have? If you move one, something else loses power. If you move a smaller amperage fuse to the circuit needing the 30A fuse, it's likely to blow again (even a 30A might if you have not solved the cause of the first fuse blowing.) When stores open, consider purchasing a resettable circuit breaker that screws into the fuse socket. Otherwise, purchase spare fuses so they are available when you need them.

Do NOT do this. If I remember correctly (the clip doesn't show the end) it didn't end so well.

if it is also 30A fuse you can swap

round fuse ? does it means it is screw in type

Think of everything that was on that circuit at the time.  Fuses usually blow on an overload.  Maybe just turned on a second or third space heater on that circuit.  This will be the easiest to stop new fuses from blowing.  Also make sure someone before did not just add a bigger fuse to that circuit, most house circuits are 15 or 20 amps.  30 amps is saved for hot water tanks or to power a sub panel.
